# in washington state can a divorce case last 32 months

Tags: divorce, washington

, i purchased divorce packet and met with someone from legal aid 2 weekends in a row where she asked the questions and i answered..she filled my answers in the blanks..she filed paperwork after i saw judge to waive cost of filing fee..i asked if i had to attend any court peoceedings and she told me no and that in 90 days id be divorced..i went out to celebrate being divoced and she babysat my kid..turns out from my research many years later i wasnt divorced for 32 months after initial filing!!..this person whod helped me to fill out the paperwork made herself a joinder to the case and i received no notices to appear for court and she went instead..my husband attended court via telephone cuz he lived in another state..he also wrote the court a letter and paid a filing fee on the same case..not once was i ever told by the woman whod  helped me with my paperwork or by my exhusband both of whod i seen during the 32 month period at least 2 times ever said anything regarding me havoing to go to court or that i was not legally divorced after 90 days..was this legal

Comment: You mention that "this person made herself a joinder to the case" – this makes no sense in this context, and reminds me of the pseudo-legal phrases used by scammers and sovereign citizens. If that person was actually your attorney they'd just represent you in court, not file their own lawsuit against your husband together with yours. Something is fishy, and you might need to talk with a real divorce lawyer.

Comment: Long divorces are rare but not unheard of. I've been a lawyer in divorces that have lasted more than five years.

Answer (score 4):

> in washington state can a divorce case last 32 months

Yes. There is no limit to the possible duration of a divorce case, especially where at least one represented party has any money. [This report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPgUMxoxFD4) showcases various instances of divorce proceedings that have lasted longer than the marriage itself because lawyers dragged the case for as long as they want. Being in Washington or New Jersey makes no difference.

Your description, including the mention that your "helper" from the divorce packet babysat your kid, suggests that you have been scammed. If you want to get divorced, it is in your best interest to learn about divorce & procedural laws of your state and then take the helm of your proceedings.

You did not specify the conditions of the divorce packet you purchased. It is therefore unclear whether the packet provider has any duty toward you in the direction of an attorney-client relation. That being said, your husband as the adversary in the proceedings has no obligation to inform you about proceedings if he already notified the person representing you in court.